# setting new href value to link tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

i'm trying to set new value to link href attribute..

```
<a title="main-picture" class="modal" href="test">
            <?php echo $this->product->images[0]->displayMediaFull('class="product-image"',false,true); ?>      
            </a>

var mainImageLink = jQuery(".product-image").attr('src');
jQuery("a[title='main-picture']").attr("href") = mainImageLink;
```

It doesnt works, i dont see any errors in console. I tried to alert jQuery("a[title='main-picture']").attr("href") - it alerted "test"

Any tips?

Comment: Post the rendered HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: Did you try reading the docs? http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: You should be getting the error "Invalid left-hand side in assignment" in your console: http://jsfiddle.net/cUPpP/

Answer (score 0):

Try instead:

```
jQuery("a[title='main-picture']").attr("href",mainImageLink);
```

To give the value to that attribute you need to use `.attr(attrName, attrValue)`.

Read more here: [**.attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: `href` is an attribute, not property.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mainImageLink = jQuery(".product-image").attr('src');
jQuery("a[title='main-picture']").attr("href",mainImageLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it using simple javascript code like this.Let the links ID is link1

```
function changeLink(){
    var ele = document.getElementById("link1");
    ele.href = "newpage.html";
}
```

and now if you will click  on that link you will be redirected at newpage.html

Comment: viveksinghggits, welcome to Stackoverflow! Vanilla JS is always welcome, but your answer is incomplete. Please add also how OP could use your code and what HTML changes have to be done. Also that new function you create must be called... etc. (btw use CTR + K to make text to code in the answer box)